# Esconder mi OLEDB connectionstring en Excel

Tags: oracle, excel, oledb

Necesito esconder la contraseña o toda la cadena de conexión a personas ajenas que utilicen una determinada planilla en Excel 2010.

Para crear la conexion, sigo los siguientes pasos en Excel:

1. Pestaña "Datos"
2. Opción - "De otras fuentes"
3. Opción - "Desde el asistente para la conexión de datos."
4. Selecciono: "Microsoft Data Access - Proveedor de datos de OLEDB para Oracle"
5. Ingreso datos de conexión.
6. Siguiente, Siguiente, Finalizar.

El tema es que si alguien ingresa a las propiedades de conexión luego de creada, puede visualizar datos importantes como por ejemplo el usuario, contraseña y servidor de mi base de datos, es por ello, que consulto si alguien conoce alguna forma de ocultar la cadena de conexión que se crea.

[image: Imagen de la conexión, como la utilizo actualmente]

Alguien sabe como ?

Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

¿En dónde tienes guardada la cadena de conexión, en una hoja del archivo Excel?. Puedes revisar esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19163256/4092887).

Comment: Mauricio, Gracias por la bienvenida. Acabo de editar la consulta con el fin de que sea mas especifica. Revisare el enlace que me comentas. Muchas Gracias !

Comment: Tu pregunta mejoró muchísimo con tu última edición. Bien hecho.

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo esta **[respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28709110/4092887)**, y si tu no necesitas que el archivo de Excel tenga las credenciales, puedes considerar *remover la cadena de conexión luego de que exportes la información al archivo Excel:*

Sigue estos pasos:

1. Crea un archivo Excel.
2. *Sigue los mismos pasos que describes en tu pregunta*.
3. Vuelve a seleccionar la pestaña "Datos"
4. Selecciona la opción "Conexiones".
5. Selecciona la conexión existente y presiona el botón **Remover**. *En este punto te sale una advertencia similar a la de la imagen 1.*
6. Cierra la ventana de Conexiones.
7. Selecciona la opción "Propiedades".

En este punto, verás el nombre de la base de datos, pero no podrás acceder a las propiedades de la conexión.

---

*Imagen 1: Imagen que muestra el mensaje de confirmación de sale antes de remover la conexión.*
[image: Imagen que muestra el mensaje de confirmación de sale antes de remover la conexión.]

Comment: Me parece un excelente opción Mauricio, creo que es la que adoptare, de todas maneras seguiré investigando.
Siguiendo tus indicaciones, me fije que existe un apartado donde se menciona autenticacion SSS, buscare sobre aquello.

http://prntscr.com/eeobpm

Comment: @SteveKhyuga, me parece bien. Buena suerte.